# Catch error caused by incorrect web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I am looking for a way to catch an error caused by an incorrect web.config file.
It looks like `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs ev)` is only called after validating the config file and is never reached.

Example error:

> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

This error happens when the application's App pool is set to framework 2.0 instead of 4.0

When this error happens I want to redirect to a specific page with screenshots to explain how to change the App pool.

Is it possible to catch this error in global.asax?

Comment: It seems unlikely because global.asax is compiled code (and as such will only execute under 4.0)

Comment: After a lot of searching I found no way this could be done.
I can redirect to a page, but I cannot get any information about which error occurred from within the aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

try this solutuin

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

for more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: in this case you need set default redirection on IIS. You are not able to run your code witout web.config. So any part of code will not be executed. You can acich your goals only with chane setting on IIS

Comment: I was too quick with my last (now deleted) comment. The redirection is taking place but I cannot trap the error message with  Exception er = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();